# Access SQL - INSERT unmatched records

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have 3 tables - Table1 & Table2 where there are records, and Table3 where their differences should be Inserted. Here's what I have now :

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO Table3 (Field1,Field2)" & _
      "SELECT Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2" & _
      " FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table2.Field1 = Table1.Field1" & _
      " OR Table2.Field2 = Table1.Field2" &_ 
      " WHERE (((Table1.Field1) Is Null) OR ((Table1.Field2) Is Null))" & _
      " AND NOT (Table2.Field1 IS NULL AND Table2.Field2 IS NULL)"
```

This query successfully inserts unmatching records in Table3, but when I run this query once again and there shouldn't be Inserted anything anymore, query still inserts 1 record in Table3 where one of the fields in Table1 or Table2 is Null.

How can I eliminate this from happening, where's the flaw ?

EDIT : Here is sample from Tables....

```
Table1:
CompanyNo    CompanyName
111          Microsoft 
             Apple
333          Oracle

Table2:
CompanyNo    CompanyName
111          Microsoft
222          Apple
333          Oracle
             Intel
555          Google

Then Table3 should result differences:
CompanyNo    CompanyName
222          Apple
             Intel
555          Google
```

And on first run of code result is correct, but when I run It again, "Intel" record is shown again - but It shouldn't because all new data from Table2 is allready in Table1 (I'm doing INSERT and UPDATE to Table1 after this Query, so "Intel" record is allready in Table1 then).

Comment: It might have something to do with the `OR` in `JOIN ON` clause.

Comment: Yes, probably. But I have tried all sorts of combinations with AND,OR and ON, LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN and can't eliminate that empty Insert on second run.

Comment: Something is not clear to me. Running again the append query will add the same number of records again to the table. There is no check that the records are already in the table. So If it appends 10 records for the first time then it will do it again at the second, third... time. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's a little bit complicated to explain - but in short - a lot of queris are being  used after this query for Table 1. But for this Query : everything gets deleted from Table3 before executing Queries, so NO there are no records allready in the table. This table is used for displaying data that were changed when Importing new ones in Table1, but problem is second run of code, where It Inserts record in Table3 with blank field that is allready in Table1, unchanged.

Comment: Oh ,and Table2 ? That is just used for Importing into Access, so that I can Import without duplicates to Table1. So that's why Table2 is in query  - It has all new data, and Table1 has old data. And Table 3 needs differences between those two.

Comment: Forgive me @LuckyLuke82, if your last sentence is the intention how does my answer below not work which captures both side differences: 1) in table 1 and not in table 2; 2) in table2 and not in table1. You can even save a union query of these `LEFT JOIN...NULL` queries and run one append query!

Comment: No, It was answering to @ehh.Ok And I don't understand what you mean by 1.) and 2.), can you just update your answer ?

Comment: Your example is not clear. First of all, there are companies that do not have CompanyNo. Is that correct?
If yes, why Apple from Table1 is not in the unmatched list?

Comment: Apple from Table1 is in unmatched list, as "222 Apple". As mentioned in EDIT of question, there are other queries executed after this desired query (INSERT and UPDATE). So, when that is done, Table1 get's UPDATED in record Apple as "222 Apple". So, in second run of code - record Apple is same in Table1 and Table2, and It's not Inserted in Table3 anymore....BUT, record "Intel" which has one field empty & is also same in Table1 and Table2 IS INSERTED, and It shouldn't be because It exists in both tables. I hope now you get the picture, I'm sorry for not being clear, but It's complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You only want the fields from `Table2`, so I would use `not exists`:

```
select t2.Field1, t2.Field2
from table2 as t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 as t1
                  where (t1.field1 = t2.field1 or t1.field1 is null and t2.field1 is null) or
                        (t1.field2 = t2.field2 or t1.field2 is null and t2.field2 is null)
                 );
```

You might get similar results if you move the `NULL` comparison logic to the `on` clause.  But that might not be possible in MS Access.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but It didn't work. Exactly as you wrote didn't do nothing, but when adding " INSERT INTO Table3....) above your first select - then It doesn't Insert records where there is one field Null, even on first run of code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting up the append queries into two actions, capturing Table 1 and Table 2 differences respectively. Right now, you are attempting to combine both differences and the empty insert is differences lying on the non-referenced select columns from Table 1:

```
table1diffSQL = "INSERT INTO Table3 (Field1,Field2)" & _
                "SELECT Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2" & _
                " FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1" & _
                " AND Table1.Field2 = Table2.Field2" & _  
                " WHERE ((Table2.Field1) Is Null OR (Table2.Field2) Is Null)"


table2diffSQL = "INSERT INTO Table3 (Field1,Field2)" & _
                "SELECT Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2" & _
                " FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1" & _
                " AND Table1.Field2 = Table2.Field2" & _
                " WHERE ((Table1.Field1) Is Null OR (Table1.Field2) Is Null)"
```

**EDIT** (per OP's sample data)

```
SELECT Table2.CompanyNo, Table2.CompanyName
FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1
ON  Table1.CompanyNo = Table2.CompanyNo
AND Table1.CompanyName = Table2.CompanyName
WHERE Table1.CompanyNo Is Null OR Table1.CompanyName Is Null
```

Results

```
CompanyNo   CompanyName
      222   Apple
            Intel
      555   Google
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I tried but It didn't work. Are you sure that you didn't make mistakes ? Because I see simmiliar lines in your JOIN - Table1.field1=Table2.Field2  AND Table1.Field2=Table2.Field2 is in both clauses ?...However, your suggestions Inserts all records that have one field empty, and only that, nothing else.

Comment: Yes, `JOIN` statements are the same but `FROM` tables and `WHERE` clauses differ. If you are trying to capture differences of either fields between both tables, then this should work. Can you provide some type of sample data and desired results?

Comment: how ? Can I paste file here ?

Comment: Just add sample data to your post. A few lines of Table 1 and 2 with how Table 3 should result.

Comment: Here It is, check my edited question, I hope you'll now understand.

Comment: See edit. The second query I originally posted worked.

Comment: Yes, I have. If you mean only second query, that doesn't work. It does just about same thing as my query - on first run result is correct, on second run It still Inserts "Intel" in Table3. Is this some kind of error that Access has with NULL values ? Or would I have to add another "UPDATE" query to Table3, maybe I can't solve this with INSERT only ?

Comment: Run your append query in the Access create query window and not through VBA and see if you receive conversion errors. Table3 possibly has required fields and other validation rules.

Comment: I did, If you mean your solution It didn't work. I get all null values as said before. However, I tried same for @eeh suggestion, and Access returned me "The INSERT statement contains the following unknown field name". And spell-checking is correct. Either Access doesn't doesn't support UNION, either clause is not correctly written.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a small example in order to be sure we are on the same page.

[image]

If this is what you are looking for so you can use UNION ALL.

```
INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Table1.Field1 , Table1.Field2 FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON     
Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1 WHERE Table2.Field1 is Null 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Table2.Field1 , Table2.Field2 FROM Table2 LEFT JOIN Table1 ON     
Table1.Field1 = Table2.Field1 WHERE Table1.Field1 is Null 
)  AS UnMatchedTable;
```

As I said before, running it again will add the same records again.

Comment: @eeh, I tried, but nothing is done. First - INSERT without "(Field1,Field2)" ?....and second - what is "AS UnmatchedTable" doing in clause ? If query will work there shouldn't be added any records in second run - because Table1 and Table2 don't have any different records then.

Comment: INSERT without "(Field1,Field2)" ? It is a valid syntax.
As UnmatchedTable, is just a name to the temp table returned from the nested part.
Running the query again and again will add records to Table3 since they are independent.